# Keycloak edit .ftl files

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I would like to add custom Java code to Keycloak's FTL file. The problem is that I have to display some information from an external API.
So the procedure is:
Keycloak login page -> [if the login is successful login] Keycloak custom Page which displays the information for the external REST API for X seconds -> Navigate to the actual application.

The most logical and easy solution is to edit the actual application to display this information but unfortunately, I don't have access to the application's code.

So I need a way to edit the FTL files of Keycloak in order to be able to write Java inside and display it on labels.

Comment: if you just want to extend an existing page, you have to create your own theme which inherits the default keycloak theme. you can check the documentation https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_development/topics/themes.adoc . to load your theme you can create a jar which contains it or copy it to the themes folder of keycloak. if you want to add some custom page you have to build your own jar (containing an authenticator) + custom theme (your FTL) . further then you have to switch to your theme (which is inheriting the default)

Comment: and add your authenticator to the default login flow.

Comment: @user1519979 how about if you want to add some javascript code for a element validation? Can you do it by editing the .ftl? Please share an example if possible.